# How to make broadcast only for that particular activity live in android

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I want to make a broadcast only for particular activity. If activity get destroy then broadcast will not trigger.
I am using like this

```
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver((receiver),
                new IntentFilter(GCMIntentService.COPA_RESULT)
        );
    }
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int count = intent.getIntExtra(GCMIntentService.COPA_MESSAGE, 0);
                int youCount = intent.getIntExtra(GCMIntentService.COUNT_YOU, 0);
                int reqCount = intent.getIntExtra(GCMIntentService.COUNT_REQ, 0);
                if (count != 0) {
                    notificationcount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    notificationcount.setText("" + count);
                } else {
                    notificationcount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                AppCommon.notification_requestcount = reqCount;
                AppCommon.notification_youcount = youCount;
                AppCommon.notification_total_count = count;
            }
        };
```

What I am missing please suggest this

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so do edit the question with that, to save down votes!

Comment: Are you trying to receive or send broadcast in your activity ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this then , simply do one thing register Broadcast receiver in Activity itself and unregister in same Activity. Like following

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver((receiver),
                new IntentFilter(GCMIntentService.COPA_RESULT)
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onStop();
    }

 receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int count = intent.getIntExtra(GCMIntentService.COPA_MESSAGE, 0);
                int youCount = intent.getIntExtra(GCMIntentService.COUNT_YOU, 0);
                int reqCount = intent.getIntExtra(GCMIntentService.COUNT_REQ, 0);
                if (count != 0) {
                    notificationcount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    notificationcount.setText("" + count);
                } else {
                    notificationcount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                AppCommon.notification_requestcount = reqCount;
                AppCommon.notification_youcount = youCount;
                AppCommon.notification_total_count = count;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Let me try and check

Answer (score 0):

Create receiver inside `Activity` and add property. Same time if you want the receiver to be destroyed when `Activity` destroyed `register` and `unregister` on `onResume()` and `onPause()` respectively.

Demo:

Create `BroadcastReceiver` on your Activity:

```
 private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // your methods and actions for receiver
    }
 };
```

Register broadcast in your activity's `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    your_activity_.this.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(your_filter_action));
    ..
    ...
    ....
  }
```

Don't forget to unregistered/register on Activity cycle:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    your_activity.this.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(your_filter_action));

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    your_activity.this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);

}
```

Comment: Ok. I will try this way also for implementing the functionality

Comment: @Abhinavkorpal, Consider accepting answer if helped !

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to unregister your broadcast receiver, Please check.

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onStop();
    }
```